# How to logout a page without affecting other pages?

Tags: php

There are two login pages and if one page is logged out other also automatically getting logged out how to change that?

adminlogout.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['ADMIN_UNAME']);
    session_destroy();
    header("location: adminlogin.php?logout=true");
 ?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
  session_destroy();
  header("location: login.php");
?>
```

Comment: dont use `session_destroy()`

Comment: As mentioned above, you are destroying the entire session, don't do that, instead invalidate the login that you wish to logout from.

Comment: @Epodax What does session store apart from global variables. Is it necessary to destroy all of them when user logouts?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove session_destroy() function. session_destroy() delete complete session information for request with sessionid from the server. Hence both scripts logouts.

adminlogout.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['ADMIN_UNAME']);
    header("location: adminlogin.php?logout=true");
 ?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
  header("location: login.php");
?>
```

Comment: What does session store apart from global variables. Is it necessary to destroy all of them when user logouts?

Comment: For a particular request from a client(browser) all the session data is stored in file under tmp folder file - sess_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX. when a user logouts just delete the information pertaining to the user. In your case since two separate logins are there for adminlogout and logout

Comment: Then shouldn't we destroy the tmp folder

Comment: No please dont destroy tmp folder its a server level stuff.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `session_destroy();` you completely remove everything the server knows about your current session. Note a session survives while the current browser instance is open, if you destroy the session you destroy all the session globals.

If you want to logout of just the admin or a normal user you should just change a session variable to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already pointed out, the problem is the call of `session_destroy()` as this destroy the whole session.

But I'd like to add that you should maybe consider using a multidimensional array in your session for different purposes or, what is even better, use different sessions as they are in completely different areas (e.g. the admin session should definitely not be shared with a normal user session, using HTTPS cookies, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

unset the session variable or make the session variable as empty in logout.php

```
   adminlogout.php
    <?php
        session_start();
         $_SESSION['ADMIN_UNAME']='';
        header("location: adminlogin.php?logout=true");
     ?>




 logout.php
    <?php
    session_start();
       $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']='';
        header("Location:login.php");

    ?>
```